Is every strongly singly generated type $II_1$ factor generated by a pair of hyperfinite $II_1$ subfactors with a common MASA?
A type $II_1$ factor $M$ is strongly singly generated (SSG) if every amplification $M^{t}$ of $M$ is singly generated as a von Neumann algebra. Interesting characterizations of SSG type $II_1$ factors, and intriguing questions about this property, can be found in this paper of Sorin Popa. All inclusions in the following question are unital.

Question: Given an arbitrary SSG type $II_1$ factor $M$, can it be generated as a von Neumann algebra by a pair $R_{0}, R_{1}$ of hyperfinite subfactors such that that there is an abelian von Neumann subalgebra $A$ of $M$ contained in $R_{0}\cap R_{1}$ so that $A$ is maximal abelian in both $R_{0}$ and $R_{1}$?

I believe that this has a negative answer, but don't have a counterexample.

If all interpolated free group factors are singly generated (for example, if the free group factor problem has a positive answer), then any free group factor would give a counterexample. (Or, if $L(\mathbb{F}_\infty)$ is finitely generated, that would give a counterexample as well.)

@DavidGao: Right! This is essentially the reason for the question: an affirmative answer to the question as posed implies the free group factors are non-isomophic. It seems too ambitious to expect this to be true, though.

To clarify: I believe that the free group factors are non-isomophic, but an affirmative answer to the question I've asked here seems like too much to expect. But maybe I am wrong...

I mean, I wouldn’t expect the free group factor problem be solved this way, and certainly people have made this observation before, so this question certainly cannot have a known positive answer. Several other potential counterexamples here: as mentioned in the paper you linked to, any factor with Cartan, any factor with property Gamma, and any non-prime factor are all SSG. If $L(SL_3(\mathbb{Z}))$ has a nontrivial fundamental group (which, IIRC, is open), then it has SSG…

… Then again, the only way I know to prove no such $R_0$ and $R_1$ exists uses 1-bounded entropy, and apart from free group factors, every potential counterexample I mentioned has non-positive 1-bounded entropy, so I wouldn’t know where to start proving no such $R_0$ and $R_1$ exists.

I would expect the answer to this question is negative as well, but I’d also expect it’s open at the moment. If a counterexample is known, though, I would think Stefaan Vaes, who’s also on MathOverflow, would likely know about it. I’d suggest asking him.
